# How to duplicate tab via keyboard only in Google Chrome?

Tags: macos, keyboard, google-chrome, contextual-menu

Is there a way to duplicate a Chrome tab in macOS via keyboard only?

Showing the menu option to do this.

[image: Screenshot of the contextual menu for a Tab inside of Google Chrome with the 'Duplicate' option selected]

There are a lot of keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, is there a way to duplicate a tab from the keyboard?

Comment: Do you mean duplicate an already opened tab?

Comment: There are various questions with answers on how to bind menu entries to keyboard shortcuts on this site. Did you try some of them, what was the result?

Comment: hi, @nohillside. thanks for your response.
i found the way to create custom shortcut for for specific applications, but it does not work with the duplication tab. i do not know why:
https://imgur.com/a/i9Hx872

Comment: @IconDaemon exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two answers below:

1. Keyboard shortcut to duplicate Google Chrome tab, keeping URL history and general position on the webpage, in macOS. This uses Automator running an AppleScript.
2. Old answer: Simple keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd>, but doesn't keep URL history nor general position on the webpage. This shortcut is mentioned somewhere in [Is there a shortcut key to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/284115/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-duplicate-a-tab-in-google-chrome).

#### 1. Keyboard shortcut to duplicate Chrome tab, keeping URL history

To duplicate a Chrome tab while retaining URL history, you can run the following AppleScript using Automator, and assign this task to a keyboard shortcut in System Settings:

1. Open Automator and choose **Quick Action**.
2. Search for and drag **Run AppleScript** from the left side to the main workflow window.
3. Copy and paste the following into the **Run AppleScript** box:

```AppleScript
on run {input, parameters}
    
    if application "Google Chrome" is running then
        tell application "Google Chrome"
            activate
        end tell
        tell application "System Events"
            click menu item "Duplicate Tab" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Tab" of menu bar 1 of application process "Chrome"
        end tell
    end if
    
    return
end run
```

4. Set the "Workflow receives" to "no input". It should look like this now:

[image: AppleScript script in Automator to duplicate Chrome tab]

5. Save the script (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) and enter the name "Duplicate Chrome tab". The script will be saved in the default directory `~/Library/Services/`.
6. You've created the script with Automator and saved it, now you need to install it to make it visible to System Settings. Go to `~/Library/Services/` and open the script up again, this time it uses the default app "Automator Installer", now press <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> once more to save and now install it. This makes the service visible in System Settings.
7. Open **System Settings** > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Shortcuts...** > **Services** > **General**, and tick the checkmark next to **Duplicate Chrome tab**, and assign a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
8. Open Google Chrome to a tab with some URL history, then press your keyboard shortcut. If you get a pop-up window saying you need permissions, make sure you allow it inside System Settings.
9. Voila, you now have a keyboard shortcut to duplicate a Chrome tab with URL history, and this also remembers your general placement within the webpage.

#### 2. Keyboard shortcut to duplicate Chrome tab, without URL history

This was my old answer, but it doesn't retain URL history nor does it remember your placement within a webpage:

Press <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select the current URL, then <kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Return</kbd> to duplicate the current tab.

[Is there a shortcut key to duplicate a tab in Google Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/284115/is-there-a-shortcut-key-to-duplicate-a-tab-in-google-chrome)

Comment: Hi @Aeronautix, thanks for your response. This is good enough to copy the URL and create a new tab, but it does not 'duplicate' it.
'Duplicate' means, for example, that in the new tab, I can go 'Back' to the previous URL in the history.

Comment: Hi, I tried duplicating the tab using AppleScript + Google Chrome, where I told AppleScript to use the menu bar of Google Chrome: --> Tab --> Duplicate Tab, but this did not work to retain URL history for some reason. I might look into using a "mouse clicker" program to click on "Tab" then on "Duplicate Tab", but I have limited knowledge with such programs right now, but I will report back if I find anything.

Comment: I got AppleScript to work, answer has been updated.

Comment: amazing! good work! Accepted! @Aeronautix

Answer (score 0):

I do not really like this solutions, but it works from the keyboard only:

1. In chrome create a bookmark (right click in the bookmark bar -> 'Add Page').
2. Edit the url to be:

   `javascript:(function(){ var url = window.location.href; window.open(url, '_blank');})();`
3. Edit the name to be "Duplicate Tab"
4. Save

If you want to duplicate the current tab, type cmd + L (edit current url) and type "Duplicate Tab" and enter.
if you have a tool to run a script from a keyboard shortcut (like Raycast) it will be even faster